# Laravel Blade Loading An Image From Public Storage - 403 (Forbidden)

Tags: php, html, laravel, image, laravel-blade

In one of my **blade views**, I am trying to display an **image** by doing:

```
<img src="<?php echo asset("storage/uploads/iotpark/warranty/$currentFile")?>"></img>
```

The image is stored in my-website.com>public>storage>uploads>iotpark>warranty.

However, when visiting the page on my browser, the image is not loaded and when inspecting in Chrome's console, the following error is shown:

```
GET https://my-website.com/storage/uploads/iotpark/warranty/48_00C1D156_1602499479.jpg 403 (Forbidden)
```

I have run `php artisan storage:link` in my server's command prompt, and the **links were created**.

- **This worked well locally** and I did not have any errors. Only happening online.

What could it be caused by please?

Thanks a lot!
Brian

Comment: welcome to SO .. make sure your uploading image in `public` like `Storage::disk('public')->put()`

Comment: delete the symlink and create it again with `php artisan storage:link`, if that not work, then you need to create symlink from your project root by command `ln -s ../storage/app/public public/storage`